# How to close other window by python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have following python code in Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk


def main_gui(login, s):
    login.quit()  # close login window

    win = tk.Tk()
    win.geometry('300x150') 

    name = tk.Label(win, text='Hello' + s.get())  # Hello David
    name.pack()
    win.mainloop()

# initial Tkinter frame
login = tk.Tk()
login.title('Login')
login.geometry('300x150')

# input user name
user_name_var = tk.StringVar()
user_name_var.set('David')
tk.Label(login, text='User name').place(x=10, y=50)
user_name = tk.Entry(login, textvariable=user_name_var)
user_name.place(x=100, y=50)

input_ok = tk.Button(win_login, command=lambda: main_gui(login, user_name), text='OK', width=15)
input_ok.place(x=100, y=90)

win_login.mainloop()
```

I want to close login window, but my code can not close it. How to solve it.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to have two `tk.Tk()` instances/mainloops. If you want another window use `tk.Toplevel()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - only two details you have to adapt:

1. The method to remove a widget in Tkinter is `destroy`, so `login.quit()` should be `login.destroy()`.
2. Once `login` is destroyed, the `user_name Entry` will also be destroyed, and you will not be able to `get` the name from it anymore. You should get the name earlier, e.g., directly in the lambda:

   `... lambda: main_gui(login, user_name.get()), ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
root.withdraw()
```

function, this will close the window without completely destroying all of the root.after functions